# Is there a way to set the Amazon S3 link URL in Lambda all from the AWS-CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cli

[image: things I want configured]

Basically, I want to know if I can configure everything you see in this image from the AWS CLI. It seems like I can't.

Can I modify this Lambda config to provide an S3 link and function handler all from the CLI?

Comment: Yes and yes. What did you try? What didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the [`create-function`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/create-function.html) call.

```
aws lambda create-function \
--runtime python3.6 \
--handler file_name.lambda_handler \
--code S3Bucket=mybucket,S3Key=path/to/object.zip
```

Comment: Ah, but can this overwrite an existing Lambda rather than creating a new one? Thanks though, this is a great start!

Comment: To modify an existing Lambda, use update-function-code and update-function-configuration.

Comment: Also have a look at the SAM CLI https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli It helps you with packaging and deploying. You'll have to define a Cloudformation template first though.

Comment: @AlwaysQuestioning highly recommend running 'aws lambda help' to see what actions are available and then 'aws lambda update-function-code help' etc. for more details on each action.